# white screen on native android package

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I tried the "device" example present at location "~\sencha-touch-2.0.1.1\examples\device" .
when I run it through browser it runs fine
But when I convert the same to native android package and run that APk file on a Nexus 7 tablet , I get a white screen with no errors on the "log" console.

It's not working Can anyone help please?

Comment: how do you convert it to apk? If Sencha Cmd which version and if Phonegap which version?

Comment: i used sencha cmd version 3.1

Comment: What is the API level you've chosen?

Comment: Android API 17 in my .json file